# Google Sheet IMPORTRANGE Error "Import Range internal error" When Range is just a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheet IMPORTRANGE function for single column in rage

`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bCoiKLjBlM5IGRo9wrdm", "sheet1!B:B")`
I get

> "Import Range internal error."

But for

`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bCoiKLjBlM5IGRo9wrdm", "sheet1!B:C")`, it works.

Is it a bug? up to now, it was the third time that I had to change them many times? Is there any consistent solution for it?
I use this solution as temporary

```
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bCoiKLjBlM5IGRo9wrdm", "sheet1!B:C") , "Select Col1")
```

Finally:

> I didn't get error for 5 day right now
> And in this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204097721 has now been marked as fixed in the issue tracker.

Comment: In addition to doubleunary's answer, you should also keep your range constrained so as to not important lots of dead rows. So something like `B:B5000` instead of `B:B`.

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with "columns" - maybe edit your guestion?

Comment: Created an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204097721

Comment: The issue has now been marked as fixed in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204097721#comment53).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could not be the solution to the problem.
I have built a whole data integration platform up on sheets and rely heavily on `importrange` functionality to shield off access to datasources from users.
Now lately the #REF started to haunt my tables all over the place and it renders everything more or less unusable.

Definately this is a bug or lack of resources.

Answer (score 7):

These errors are usually temporary and go away in a few hours. To expedite that, modify your import formula slightly by replacing `"Sheet1!B1:B"` with `"Sheet1!B:b"` — the switch to partial lowercase is enough to let the call duck Google's cache and get fresh results, which should let you work around the issue.

To automate that to an extent, use this pattern:

`=iferror( importrange("...", "Sheet1!B1:B"), importrange("...", "Sheet1!B:b") )`

Also see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/131278661.

Comment: Thanks. That worked even for a named range.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution here is to use

```
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bCoiKLjBlM5IGRo9wrdm", "sheet1!B:C") , "Select Col1")
```

Comment: Have you any idea, why this would help?
I'm giving it a try, anyways, thanks.

Comment: In my case, the useful formula looks like this:  `=query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...", "sheetname!A:H"), "select *")`

Answer (score 1):

There is a dirty solution that could be used temporarily. It does not shield you completely from that issue, it might still occur.

This:

```
IMPORTRANGE("id", "A:A")
```

Could be replaced with that (notice lower different case in the same range being imported 2nd time):

```
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("id", "A:A"), IMPORTRANGE("id", "A:a"))
```

I've seen this solution posted [here](https://t.me/google_spreadsheets_chat/209416) by Vitaly, he got it from [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/131278661).

Comment: The `iferror()` recipe is from https://support.google.com/docs/thread/131278661.

Answer (score 1):

I try this solution, it works

Before `IMPORTRANGE("id", "a:b")`

Now `IMPORTRANGE("id", "A:b")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ducking Google's cache is a fix or even a workaround.

We've maintained a sheet with the importrange function across multiple tabs for years, and only within the last week has there been a problem.

We first noticed it on Friday then it came back again today. In both instances, I don't think I did anything to fix the issue, especially today. I moved the formula around on the sheet, which had the effect of refreshing the importrange function, but it still resulted in the "Import Range internal error." The importrange function went down for a time (I don't know how long  today, but I think it was at least 15 minutes) and then resolved itself on all tabs without a modification.

I think this definitely a bug or Google messing with stuff on the back-end. Maybe we need to find a way to do everything without using importrange?

Answer (score 0):

I Tried using following and solve my problem since last 2 days...

```
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("id", "A1:B20"),iferror(IMPORTRANGE("id", "A1:b20"),iferror(IMPORTRANGE("id", "a1:B20"),IMPORTRANGE("id", "a1:b20"))))
```

Means, Recall same fuctions 4x times using CAPS/Non CAPS in Range names.

Comment: If you add a sheet name to the range you'll get much more case change options. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same situation, but found a solution that worked for us.

We had 1 sheet that was importing ranges from 2 separate sheets (call A & B).

A was importing correctly.
B was showing the Internal Import Error.

I also noticed that on Sheet B, I was unable to view Version Histories.
However, Sheet A I was able to view Version Histories.
--Makes sense that this is where the issue would be, because ImportRange pulls from the most recent Version saved.

THE FIX -- I cleared my Chrome's Cache from the last 7 days (experiencing the issue for 3 days)
Then had to re-sign into my account and the ranges were importing successfully!

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Side note -- A coworker traveled to Canada from the US 3 days ago at the same time the Internal Error showed up.  Possibly could be from international server errors?? That is a very weird theory, but who knows...